# WPF Can the animation reverse be invoked explicitly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Animations in WPF provide the boolean parameter `AutoReverse`. Is it possible to make a call to the functionality implemented by `AutoReverse = "true"`?

My goal is to spare some troublesome reverse animation and especially spare alot of code. The reverse must not happen directly after the animation ended.

---

Example of using AutoReverse and True to animate only the reverse animation, but this does not work as required - it still animates the actual animation and the reverse animation.

```
        TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform(0.0, 0.0);
        myBox.RenderTransform = transform;

        sb = new Storyboard();
        Duration dur = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
        DoubleAnimation shiftAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(100.0, dur);
        shiftAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
        sb.Children.Add(shiftAnimation);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(shiftAnimation, myBox);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(shiftAnimation, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.X"));

        sb.Seek(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
        sb.Begin();
```

Comment: try sb.Begin(this,true);

and maybe to pause it, and afte that to seek it and then to rsume!


something like

`sb.Begin(this,true);
sb.Pause();
sb.Seek(sb.Duration.TimeSpan);
sb.Resume();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could set the timeclock to 100% of the animationduration so when the animation starts, it will skip the non-reversed part!

Edit:
if Duration is set to 0:0:1.5 you apply a new timeline to your animation set to 0:0:1.5. Autoreverse has to be set to on and then you yust have to start the animation.

Edit 2:

```
TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform(0.0, 0.0);
myBox.RenderTransform = transform;

sb = new Storyboard();
Duration dur = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
DoubleAnimation shiftAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(100.0, dur);
shiftAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
sb.Children.Add(shiftAnimation);
Storyboard.SetTarget(shiftAnimation, myBox);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(shiftAnimation, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.X"));

sb.Begin();
sb.Pause();
sb.Seek(sb.Duration.TimeSpan);
sb.Resume();
```

Comment: @Kerwindena: This sounds amazingly reasonable. So the path of action would be: Define my own reverse() function which applies the just defined animation but adds AutoReverse and Timeclock set to 100%?

Comment: @platzhirsch: normally this should work. but you cannot set the timeclock to 100% just set the timeclock to the same value as the duration of the animation... Good Luck!

Comment: @Kerwindena: How do you apply a new timeline? An animation is a timeline, but I cannot find a member field which declares the animation clock.

Comment: @platzhirsch: Storyboard.ApplyAnimationClock

Comment: @platzhirsch: or you jump with .Seek to the specific position, wich might be a lot easier

animation.Seek(animation.Duration.TimeSpan);

Comment: @Kerwindena: Please see my code example in the original question post. It does not work this way. The animation is done anyway, it does not jump to the end of the animation.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that the following code works nicely:

```
              private bool reverse=false;
              TimeSpan animationDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
              Storyboard storyboard1 = new Storyboard();                      

              private void prepareStoryBoard(Button btn)
              {
                btn.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
                DoubleAnimation animationShrink = new DoubleAnimation() { To = 0, 
                  Duration =animationDuration , FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd };
                storyboard1.Children.Add(animationShrink);
                Storyboard.SetTarget(animationShrink, btn);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationShrink,
                  "(Button.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)");
              }

              private void toggleAnimate()
              {
                  if(reverse==false)
                    {
                        storyboard1.AutoReverse = false;
                        storyboard1.Begin();
                        reverse=true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        storyboard1.AutoReverse = true;
                        storyboard1.Seek(animationDuration);
                        storyboard1.Resume();
                        reverse = false;
                    }
              }
```

The first time toggleAnimate() is called, the animation is executed in the normal direction, the second time toggleAnimate() is invoked the animation is reversed.